# how to update displaying user input text in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm writing a basic program with pygame that in some part needs to take an text input from the user. My problem is that when the user wants to erase part of the text, the old text keeps displaying it in the pygame window.
Let's say the user types '23' and then presses backspace. The console shows 2 but the pygame window will keep displaying 23.
I'm using:

```
if event.key == pg.K_BACKSPACE:
   text = text[:-1]
```

Comment: You have to (re)render the text surface after changing the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to (re)render the text surface after changing the text and you have to clear the display in every frame:

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 200))
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

text = ""
text_surf = font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False  
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE: 
                text = text[:-1]
            else:
                text += event.unicode 
            text_surf = font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))        

    window_center = window.get_rect().center

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    window.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(center = window_center))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)